# JQuery Promise is Undefined in SharePoint OnPrem

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, promise, undefined

**ENVIRONMENT**
SharePoint 2013 On-Prem
NO INTERNET ACCESS
jquery-1.10.2.js is in the 15 Hive

**SETUP**
TimeLog.aspx is a site page with a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP).
 
Timelog.html is in a Site Assets library, and is linked to by the CEWP.
Timelog.js is also in the Site Assets library, and is linked to Timelog.html.
myJSLib.js is also in the Site Assets library, and is linked to TimeLog.html.

Timelog.html:

```
<script src=".../myJSLib.js"></script>
<script src=".../Timelog.js"></script>
```

TimeLog.js:

```
$fjq(document).ready(function($) {
   if (!IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup('my group')) { //do something }
```

myJSLibrary.js:

```
function IsCurrentUserMemberofGroup(grpName) {
    return new promise(function(resolve, reject) { //do something }
```

**ERROR**
*promise is not defined*

In F12, I can see that jquery-1.10.2.js is loaded, so what (else) do I need to do to make sure that my code can see it, such that I can use a jQuery Promise?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, and you should be aware that the need to create a new promise in this way is rare; you probably don't need to do so.

Comment: I have a custom report page, with dynamic criteria controls and a search button. I want the criteria controls to populate, prior to the Search button being enabled. I want to avoid the Asynch call pyramid, and use promises to simplify all the code. I have solved this using: var dfd = $.Deferred(function(){ //do something }, but I prefer the return new promise syntax instead. So, why doesn't the return new promise syntax work?

Comment: "*I want the criteria controls to populate, prior to the Search button being enabled.*" - doesn't sound like something that would require a promise. I'm still not convinced that you need one.

Comment: I have an asynch call that occurs. When it doesn't finish, it doesn't display any values in the one of the controls. The control is a required entry. So, if the user were to click the Search button, it will trigger a validation error. Thus, there's no point in enabling the button until the control is populated. What technique would you use instead to ensure population prior to enabling?